# How do I extract the Subject Alternative Name from a CSR by just using the openssl command?

Tags: openssl

I would need to extract the Subject Alternative Name from a CSR. Is there any way I can extract this other than using the "-text" in openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout? (Maybe similar with the -subject parameter?)

I noticed that the SAN is sometimes formatted as "email" and so grep DNS doesn't actually work well. Is there any command you can recommend which will work to get the SubjAltName correctly?

Answer (score 6):

> I would need to extract the Subject Alternative Name from a CSR...

If you look at the source code to `<openssl dir>/apps/req.c`, you will see there's nothing to extract just the SAN. But you can perform the following:

```
openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout | grep DNS
```

Here's what the output will look like on a test CSR:

```
$ openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout | grep DNS
  DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com, DNS:mail.example.com, DNS:ftp.example.com
```

It works because the Common Name (CN) is just free form text. Names in the SAN are really `GeneralName`, and they have a few different types:

```
 GeneralName ::= CHOICE {
    otherName                       [0]     OtherName,
    rfc822Name                      [1]     IA5String,
    dNSName                         [2]     IA5String,
    x400Address                     [3]     ORAddress,
    directoryName                   [4]     Name,
    ediPartyName                    [5]     EDIPartyName,
    uniformResourceIdentifier       [6]     IA5String,
    iPAddress                       [7]     OCTET STRING,
    registeredID                    [8]     OBJECT IDENTIFIER }
```

So the `DNS` prefix you are grepping for is what OpenSSL's `req` prints when it encounters a `dNSName`.

Comment: I noticed that SAN is sometimes formatted as "email" and so grep DNS doesn't actually work well. Is there any command you can recommend to work for all SANs?

Comment: @Mark - If you have an end entity certificate with an email address in the SAN, it sounds like you have user certificate rather than a server certificate. Also, you might want to ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) because it fields question on using commands. That's where you will find the experts. Stack Overflow is for programming and development questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody (like me) who stumbled upon this, I found this way:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in certificate.pem|grep -A1 'X509v3 Subject Alternative Name'|tail -n1
```

The SAN value comes one line after (the A1 grep flag) the line "X509v3...", and the tail command cuts all but the last line, the one with the SAN value.

Comment: This is the cert; not the csr :) ....i.e. x509 vs req

Comment: This also assumes that the list of SANs is on only one line.